# Design : Azure Batch <-> Azure Function

Tags: azure-batch

I am working on implementing Azure function(message based triggered) as orchestrator , which will invoke Azure Batch tasks/jobs accordingly. The number of messages varies from 10-1000 messages at a time.

Need inputs on how to configure the Azure Batch Pool(like VM node size, no. of nodes, tasks per node allocation) based on number of messages to be processed at a given time. I understand we can take advantage of AutoScale feature, any guidance with examples.

For a single message, my application(c#) takes 2 mins to process the message and generate output files on StandardA2 2vCPU, 8 GB memory node.

Regards,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are example for how to autoscale based on the number of tasks in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling#example-autoscale-formulas).